# Update input without needing to refresh page

Tags: javascript, forms, refresh, prompt

I have this simple code here:

```
var powered = prompt("my favorite color is:", "");
document.write(powered);
```

what this does is show the user and input box in which they'll enter a word. Then that word will display on the the page.

Now what I usually do is sit at the computer looking at the screen hitting the refresh button over and over to see if there's any new input

now what I'm hoping to do is: when users input information into the prompt box or form i create...I want the page to update automatically without me needing to hit "refresh" button over and over and over and over and over and....

ps.. I keep saying "prompt or form" because I also want your input on which is better to use. I know those who have pop ups turned off may not ever see the input box...but hey I like the cool pop up affect.

Answer (score 0):

i assume this is what you are looking . there are lots of ways doing this

1.basic version using java script alert box

2. prompt box
3. Jquery dialog

for more smoothness and effects use JQuery model popups.[Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display a confirm box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var x;
if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {
    x = "You pressed OK!";
 } else {
    x = "You pressed Cancel!";
 }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

[Try It Here](http://jsfiddle.net/1sja0zgx/4/) or with prompt box [Try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/ze3rX/28/)

Comment: nice button..but doesnt solve my problem. Im new to this but ill try to explain. All I want to do is look at a page on my website and see what users are writing on my site without hitting the refresh button. No hands involved. no buttons involved